# Stick div at top not working properly : javascript

Tags: javascript

I going to create a scroll and stick div which has to stick on the top of the page but while scrolling down the div next to stickdiv automatically stick to the div before to sticky div

```js
var left = document.getElementsByClassName("stickdiv");

for (var i = 0; i < left.length; i++) {
  var stop = (left[0].offsetTop);

  window.onscroll = function(e) {
    var scrollTop = (window.pageYOffset !== undefined) ? window.pageYOffset : (document.documentElement || document.body.parentNode || document.body).scrollTop;
    // left.offsetTop;
    if (scrollTop >= stop) {
      // get array item by index
      left[0].classList.add('stick'); //adding a class name
    } else {
      // get array item by index
      left[0].classList.remove('stick');
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.stickdiv {
  height: 50vh!important;
  width: 100vh!important;
  background-color: green!important;
}
.stick {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  margin: 0 0
}
#right {
  float: right;
  width: 100px;
  height: 1000px;
  background: red;
}
.des {
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="des"></div>
<div class="stickdiv"></div>
<div id="right"></div>
```

Example : green color div is the sticky div but after scrollingdown , red is also going to stick , I've tried position absolute in css but not working how to fix it

Comment: So what you want is only the red div is sticky?

Comment: yeah , but using javascript not a library

Comment: Green is going to stick *also*? Or red only? This is very confusing.

Comment: sorry @cale_b thats was consfusing , ive corrected that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the code to make green sticky when scrolling.

```js
$ = document.querySelectorAll.bind(document);
  // how far is the green div from the top of the page?
  var initStickyTop = $(".stickdiv")[0].getBoundingClientRect().top + pageYOffset;
  // clone the green div
  var clone = $(".stickdiv")[0].cloneNode(true);
  // hide it first
  clone.style.display = "none";
  // add it to dom
  document.body.appendChild(clone);
    addEventListener("scroll",stick=function() {
      // if user scroll past the sticky div
      if (initStickyTop < pageYOffset) {
        // hide the green div but the div still take up the same space as before so scroll position is not changed
        $(".stickdiv")[0].style.opacity = "0";
        // make the clone sticky
        clone.classList.add('stick');
        // show the clone
        clone.style.opacity="1";
        clone.style.display = "block";
      } else {
        // make the clone not sticky anymore
        clone.classList.remove("stick");
        // hide it
        clone.style.display = "none";
        // show the green div
        $(".stickdiv")[0].style.opacity="1";
      };
    });
    // when resize, recalculate the position of the green div
    addEventListener("resize", function() {
      initStickyTop = $(".stickdiv")[0].getBoundingClientRect().top + pageYOffset;
      stick();
    });
```

```css
.stickdiv {
  height: 50vh!important;
  width: 100vh!important;
  background-color: green!important;
}
.stick {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  margin: 0 0
}
#right {
  float: right;
  width: 100px;
  height: 1000px;
  background: red;
}
.des {
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="des"></div>
<div class="stickdiv"></div>
<div id="right"></div>
```

Comment: it's pure js. i forgot to remove jquery lib. you can remove it by yourself

Answer (score 0):

[JS FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/c2bqty6z/)

you might want to remove the stickdiv class and add it accordingly

```
if (scrollTop >= stop) {
      // get array item by index
      left[0].classList.add('stick'); //adding a class name
      left[0].classList.remove('stickdiv');
    } else {
      // get array item by index
      left[0].classList.remove('stick');
       left[0].classList.add('stickdiv');
    }
```

Comment: thanks for answer but not working @Yaje that green div goes cleared

Comment: hi, can you be more clear as to what behavior you want to achieve?

Comment: yes @cale_b , i just want to stick a div using javascript not whole library

Comment: hi cale_b. if i remove that, that would be the OPs sample code. lol

Comment: Ha! You are right! Sorry about that.  The question is very unclear.  I thought the green div should stick, but the OP says red div, which is odd.  I guess I don't understand!

Comment: is there any way to fix using javascript  I'm very new to it

Comment: Hi Anjali, Please reconstruct the question. It is Confusing. Will try to update my answer once the question is clear.

Comment: @Yaje sorry for that , i ve edited the question again